# how to filter text of the selected value in drop down

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms, filter

I have a drop down menu. Has product types. Product types have associated value (from drop down) values correspond to machine groups.

So each option should have three variables--Machine name, values, machine group.

I can get the Machine name and I can get the machine value (and display them in a different field)...what I have not been able to figure out is how to change the value into the Machine group.

```
jQuery('#MachineName').bind('change', function()
    {

      //get selected value from drop down;
        var selectedValue = jQuery("#MachineName").val();

      //populate a text field with the selected drop down value
        jQuery("#MachineValue").val(selectedValue);
```

What I would like to do is keep that MachineValue but then populate another text field with the sorted MachineGroup

I have been trying to run it through something like

```
    switch(jQuery(this).val()){
    case "236" : newVal = "8";
    break;
```

But I don't want to "change" the value I just want to do an "if then" type filter, so maybe something like:

```
    '236' => "8", '237' => "5",
```

I just don't know how to properly say "assign the MachineGroup based on the MachineValue" (and then have it populate a different text field)

In the end I would have three fields. The drop down, the MachineValue and the MachineGroup. Drop down and value are done, I just need to do Group.  (And I can sort Group based on MachineName...just not sure which would be easier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest at client side is to have server add some extra `data-` attributes to the markup. `jQuery.data()` makes it very easy to retrieve these.

html:

```
<option value="5" data-group="foo" data-name="Bar">Bar</option>
```

JS:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var $sel=$(this).find('option:selected');
    var machineGroup=$sel.data('group');
    var machineName=$sel.data('name');
    var value= $sel.val()// or $(this).val();
});
```

API ( read down below first series of examples, feature wasn't in original API)

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Thank you...this would work beautifully, but I unfortunately do not have access to add the extra data- attributes. This drop down is dynamically generated so I am stuck with being able to only work with the two existing machineName and machineValue which I cannot change/modify.

Comment: OK. Do you have an array that shows what goes in each group? Question made answering difficult without knowing what you have to work with

Comment: yes. I do. I can associate the machineGroup to either machineName or to machineValue                case "173" : newVal =  "3";        break;   or       '236' => "8", '237' => "5",        or    'kkm-444' => "8"    (kkm-444 being a machineName    173, 236, 237 being machineValue   and the 8, 5, 3 being machineGroup)

Comment: See if this helps  http://jsfiddle.net/ELu8q/. It is fairly easy to get the data to json from server usually and use this method

Comment: Thank you so much!  A little bit of tweaking and this is working wonderfully now--makes me very happy. NOW--I just need to get the form to recognize when data has been entered (vs. key stroke entered).